# D3 US map polygon for District of columbia in states map not found

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 US states map. it works fine for the 50 states. 
I need to draw District of columbia on map

I am unable to find the polygon coordinates for the DC

Please anyone can give me the co ordinates?

Comment: This appears to have D.C. (scroll down): http://datamaps.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you the coordinates since I don't know what your reference might be. However, if you use the example US map from the [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) repository, the District of Columbia has an `id` of `11001`. (The FIPS "state" code for DC is 11; the last three digits are the FIPS county code, which, for DC, don't really apply.)

Comment: yes I am using example US map from topojson repository.. DC entry is there in topojson .. I dont find polygon defined.. can we add manually?